# Почему при двойном клике на элементе Unity, элемент не приближается, а улетает?

Tags: unity3d, scrollview

Привет. Почему когда я делаю двойной клик на ScrollView в иерархии, этот ScrollView не приближается, а наоборот улетает?

Comment: Просто нужно изменить с Center на Pivot.

Answer (score 2):

У вас сама скролируемая область очень большая. Если в редакторе центр объекта стоит `Pivot`, то при двойном клике по объекту вы попадаете в центр привязки скролируемой области и камера позиционируется по по видимой части, если же выставлен "Center" то показывается центр объекта, а он идет с учетом скролируемой области которая покрыта маской, а по умолчанию при двойном клике объект показывается целиком. Скорей всего вам показывается вся скролируемая область в режиме "Center".